# Displaying only part of points in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, point, visualisation

I have a vector layer with ~30M points, which is why the layer is displayed for a very long time. And I'm not talking about further work with him yet.

Is it possible in QGIS to display only a part of the layer points based on a bounding rectangle of coordinates or something similar? Can it help in this case?

Comment: What is your goal? I don't know if there's a way to display part of a dataset, but here are some workarounds I can think of. Can you process your data without displaying it? If you are testing a workflow, you can try it first on a subset of your data (using the clip tool, for instance). Once you know the workflow works, you can extant it to the full dataset.

Comment: Why do you need to see 30 M points? Unlick Render for alla layer, or only the point layer

Comment: The goal is to identify specific sites on a high scale.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set `Scale Dependent Visibility`. Right click on the layer - Properties - Rendering. And set a minimum scale based on the spatial distribution of your data. So not the whole dataset is rendered, only at a specific scale or "zoom level". You could also consider `filtering` or `clipping` your dataset.

Comment: Thanks. Nice tool - now instead of 5 minutes to display all the points, it takes several seconds to display only a part of the points.